# How do i prevent 'Enter' from working in a div thats marked contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/7yYpe/) is a jsfiddle example. I have created a div and marked is as editable. I'm trying to capture and prevent the Enter key from inserting a new line. It looks like returning false from the event's function and stopping propagation of the event doesn't prevent the new line `<div><br></div>` (in chrome other browsers insert other stuff... trying to prevent it all...) from being inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault();` instead of `return false;`

http://jsfiddle.net/7yYpe/4/